# GEE em R-alguém consegue explicar-me o código sfv

Tags: r

```
model0 <- glm(stable  ~ Sex+Age+Height+Weight+Surface+Vision,binomial,ctsib) 
summary(model) 

model1 <- glm(stable  ~ Sex+Age+Height+Weight+Surface+Vision+factor(Subject),binomial,ctsib) 
summary(model1)
anova(model0,model1,test="Chisq")
```

Não percebo porque fazemos a comparação destes 2 modelos.
o stable é dividido em 2 categorias.

Não percebo também o que significa o "brglm" no código

```
modbr <- brglm (stable  ~ Sex+Age+Height+Weight+Surface+Vision+factor (Subject), data=ctsib) 
summary(modbr)
```

Comment: Seria melhor você ser mais específica do que você não entendeu e formatar seu código para adequar a leitura.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os objetos `model0` e `model1` são ajustes de modelos lineares generalizados (MLG) aos dados do conjunto `ctsib`. O argumento `binomial` assume que a variável resposta neste caso é binária, do tipo sucesso e fracasso. Além disso, `binomial` determina a função de ligação a ser utilizada neste MLG.

`model1` é o chamado modelo completo, que considera todas as variáveis preditoras de interesse. `model0` é o modelo reduzido, onde uma das variáveis preditoras não é considerada. Neste caso específico, a variável `Subject` ficou de fora do ajuste no `model0`. Todos as variáveis preditoras deste problema foram consideradas como efeitos fixos, embora, em geral, `Subject` seja considerado como efeito aleatório na imensa maioria destes problemas.

`anova` é a função que compara os modelos ajustados por `model0` e `model1`, a fim de verificar se há diferença significativa entre eles. O teste usado neste caso é o teste de razão de verossimilhança. O resultado deste teste vai dizer se a variável `Subject` é necessária para o ajuste dos dados deste exemplo.

Nunca utilizei a função `brglm`, mas o seu help diz o seguinte:

> Fits binomial-response GLMs using the bias-reduction method developed in Firth (1993) for the removal of the leading (O(n−1)) term from the asymptotic expansion of the bias of the maximum likelihood estimator. Fitting is performed using pseudo-data representations, as described in Kosmidis (2007, Chapter 5). For estimation in binomial-response GLMs, the bias-reduction method is an improvement over traditional maximum likelihood because:
>
> - the bias-reduced estimator is second-order unbiased and has smaller variance than the maximum likelihood estimator and
> - the resultant estimates and their corresponding standard errors are always finite while the maximum likelihood estimates can be infinite (in situations where complete or quasi separation occurs).

Ou seja, é apenas um outro método de fazer um ajuste de um GLM a dados com resposta binomial.